# Show only certain hidden files in OSX Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I do a lot of web development stuff in OSX. I need to see the `.htaccess` files in OSX Finder a lot. The only way I know how to do this is to enable viewing of all hidden files in Finder. However, this turns out to be a pain because there are so many hidden files I don't want/need to see (.DS_Store, etc).

Is there a way to selectively choose which hidden files to always have visible?

Comment: Closely related: [Show hidden files on OS X except .DS_Store](http://superuser.com/questions/31580/show-hidden-files-on-os-x-except-ds-store?rq=1) – there's no solution to this though.

Comment: Maybe [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com) works for you -- it'll move the DS_Store files out of the way so you could enable seeing all hidden files. Also, you can easily toggle hidden files visibility in *Save/Open File* dialogs by pressing `Cmd-Shift-Period`.

Comment: @DanielBeck can't get that hotkey to work. Is that a Mtn Lion thing?

Comment: Nope, has existed for many years. *Period* is the `.` key.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal run: 
`ls -a | grep -G .YOUR_EXTENSION$`
 (of course replacing "Your_Extension" with .htaccess)
that should show only .htaccess files

Comment: doesn't really apply to Finder.